# Qual é o comando para fechar ou sair do jogo criado na Unity?

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

Estou aprendendo  `Unity` e gostaria saber qual o comando para sair do jogo, ou seja fechar o aplicativo e a também ao saber esse comando como eu aplico ao apertar o botão voltar do celular `Android` executar esse tal comando.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em C# você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
            Application.Quit();

    }
}
```

Comment: me confirma se é isso mesmo a condição referida no seu código é o botão voltar do aparelho ?

Comment: Estou sem android para testar aqui, mas pelo que me lembro e pelo que pesquisei na internet, sim, é isso mesmo.

Comment: ok vou testar agora

Comment: é isso mesmo deu certo valeu fera

Answer (score 3):

No `Unity`, há parâmetros como o `Escape` que são personalizados para o software ser realmente universal. Você pode ver todas as teclas suportadas na [Documentação  do Unity](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html).

**O que seria o Escape?**

> A chave (Esc) foi criada por Bob Bemer. Ela é rotulada `Esc` ou
>   `Escape` e é geralmente usada para gerar o caractere de escape
>   `ASCII`, cujo número é `27`. Esta personagem é geralmente usada para
>   gerar uma seqüência de escape. Ela situa-se tipicamente no canto
>   superior esquerdo do teclado. Seu uso é contínuo para pequenas caixas
>   de diálogo Microsoft Windows, o que equivale a respostas como: `Não,
>   Remover, Exit, Cancelar ou Abortar`.
>
> https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_(tecla)

Logo, em dipositivos móveis essa tecla corresponderia a tecla `voltar`, seja ele Android, Windows ou iOS.

Já para fazer a saída da aplicação no Unity usamos `Application.Quit();`, que segundo sua própria documentação tem o objetivo: "*Encerrar a aplicação de jogo.*".

Agora em código como podemos fazer isso?

**C#**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetKey("escape"))
            Application.Quit();

    }
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function Update () {
    if (Input.GetKey ("escape")) {
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

Referências: [Documentação Unity 3D](http://docs.unity3d.com)