# Quais são os comando do Application no untiy 5.3?

Tags: unity3d, unity-5

Qual é o novo comando do `unity 5.3`? O `Application.Quit();` está obsoleto e já quero trocar, para não bugar, alguém podem me ajudar ?

Comment: Por que você acha que a versão 5.3 teria um comando "novo" (ou por que você acha que esse é obsoleto)? Segundo [a documentação](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.Quit.html) o `Application.Quit` existe normalmente nessa versão. E não há nenhuma informação lá sobre obsolecência.

Comment: Mais informações: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106194/qual-%C3%A9-o-comando-para-fechar-ou-sair-do-jogo-criado-na-unity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Application continua funcionando sem problemas. Mas agora eles recomandam o uso do SceneManager, para usar ele voce deve importar "using.UnityEngine.SceneManagement;".Por exemplo para mudar de cena use :  SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName);

Comment: Tá, mas e pra sair do jogo usando o `SceneManager`? Afinal, o que o `Application.Quit` faz é encerrar o jogo...

Comment: Pode continuar utilizando ele sem problemas como todas as outras funcoes do application

Comment: Eu sei que pode. Não foi isso que eu perguntei. O que eu quis dizer é: por que "agora eles recomendam o uso do SceneManager" pra encerrar a aplicação? :)

Comment: E para encerrar o jogo, o SceneManager tem essa função ?

Comment: Pelo que eu pesquisei não tem

Comment: muito obrigado pela a ajuda, desenvolve-dor de jogos tem medo de acabar bugando o jogo, kkk obg